# How to make msi in linux?

Tags: linux, compression, windows-installer

I have a msi installer created on windows, I put the msi into linux platform and I use 7z to extract content of msi installer, after that I used lcab command for extract and change some files, also using lcab command I put all files that I modified into cab. Now I need to restore msi, any idea?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `msi-packager`.
Can be installed on Ubuntu/Debian using:

```
sudo apt-get install msitools nodejs npm
sudo npm install -g msi-packager
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/msi-packager

Comment: thank for your answer, but when I install msi-packager ubuntu do not recognaize that command, what can be wront with it, because I also do that before.

Comment: Just tested this solution, and for some obscure reason it builds an MSI that shows the message "This installation package could not be opened" when run...

Comment: @AlexRock This tool is now very old and imo doesn't work. I'd avoid using it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the full procedure to manipulate MSI files under Linux. The idea is export the MSI content to XML, modify the XML and then repack de MSI file, you can modify even the EXE files, not only tables:

1. Install [WINE 32 bits version](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=29567)
2. Install **WineTricks**, you need it for DLL and frameworks installation.
3. Install .NET2.0, .NET4.0, MSXML6, VCRUN6 with winetricks (easy as ./winetricks dotnet20 dotnet40 msxml6 vcrun6)
4. Download **MSI2XML & XML2MSI** executables from the [official project page(https://msi2xml.sourceforge.io/)
5. Execute `wine msi2xml installer.msi`
6. Edit the XML file, then, pack again with `wine xml2msi installer.xml`
7. You are done, here is your MSI file!

Hope that helps, with MSI2XML & XML2MSI you can manipulate MSI files under Windows but also under Linux with WINE and it's 100% working solution.